# .htaccess url rewrites in index.php and not profile.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

So I am pretty new to url rewritting and.htaccess in general.
I would like to rewrite the url below

```
/rewrite/profile/karis/2
```

as

```
/rewrite/profile.php?name=karis&id=2
```

so the code I have for my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^profile profile.php

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ profile.php?name=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ profile.php?name=$1&id=$2
```

So this works perfectly when I change everything to work for `index.php` but the same code does not work on `profile.php`.

The simple php code is

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        echo "Hi ".$_GET['name'].", your id is ".$_GET['id'];   
    }
?>
```

Any Ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules can all be combined into one and first one is misplaced also. Try this in your `/rewrite/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /rewrite/

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ profile.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^profile/?$ profile.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you enter URL as `http;?/example.com/profile/karis/2`? Did you use `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` in your .htaccess?

Comment: But in your question your URLs start with `/rewrite/`. Which one is correct? Can you tell me what is location of this .htaccess and what exact URL did you enter in your browser?

Comment: oh, sorry about that.. rewrite is the main folder.
so basically, the code works on localhost/rewrite/index.php but not localhost/rewrite/profile.php

Comment: check update code, it goes in `/rewrite/.htaccess` not in root .htaccess.